# Gaussian approximation of old states

Tags: statistics, computer-vision, filtering

I came across the following sentence referred to the usual Extended Kalman Filter and I'm trying to make sense of it:

> States before the current state are approximated with a normal distribution

What does it mean?

Comment: can you give a source for that quote? I'd like to see the context to understand the quote

Answer (score 1):

the modeled quantity has uncertainty because it is derived from measurements. you can't be sure it's exactly value X. that's why the quantity is represented by a probability density function (or a cumulative distribution function, which is the integral of that).

a probability distribution can look very arbitrary but there are many "simple" distributions that approximate the real world. you've heard of the normal distribution (gaussian), the uniform distribution (rectangle), ...

the normal distribution (parameters mu and sigma) occurs everywhere in nature so it's likely that your measurements already fit a normal distribution very well.

"*a* gaussian" implies that your distribution isn't a mixture (sum) of gaussians but a single gaussian.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand how in the EKF this is done: when are we assuming the old states to be gaussian? To me it looks that every time step t we are modeling the state X_t as a non-linear function of the previous state X_t-1 + a gaussian error. So, one could say X_t conditioned on X_t-1 is gaussian. But I don't think it is the correct way of seeing this..

Comment: that is the extent of my understanding of kalman filters. I hope you'll get responses from other people. google didn't know anything about that sentence you quoted so it must not have come out of any accessible publication.